# Passing lambda function as Parameter to threading.Thread

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im new to python so forgive me if Im not applying best practices and I welcome any feedback to help doing the code below the python way. I have the following code and the out put is making me very confused and not sure how to fix in order to get the expected output. Im getting the name Sal on both greetings:

```
    from time import sleep
    import threading
    
    def printGreating(get_greeting):
        sleep(5)
        greeting = get_greeting()
        print(greeting)
    
    
    def createGreeting(greeting,name):
        return greeting+' '+ name
    
    
    
    nameslist = ["Sam","Sal"]
    threads = []
    
    for n in nameslist:
        print(n)
    
        if n == "Sam":
    
            create_greeting_l = lambda : createGreeting("Hello",n)
    
        else:
    
            create_greeting_l = lambda : createGreeting("Greeting",n)
    
    
        t = threading.Thread(target=printGreating, args=(create_greeting_l,))
    
        t.start()
    
        threads.append(t)
    
    for t in threads:
    
        t.join()
    
    
print('-------------------Completed--------------')

Expected output:

Sam
Sal
Hello Sam
Greeting Sal
-------------------Completed--------------

What Im getting:
Sam
Sal
Greeting Sal
Hello Sal
```

Expected output:

Sam
Sal
Hello Sam
Greeting Sal

What Im getting:
Sam
Sal
Greeting Sal
Hello Sal

UPDATED Dec 22,2022:

I finally figured out the fix. the name should be passed as parameter to the lambda funntion:

```
if n == "Sam":
        
        create_greeting_l = lambda a : createGreeting("Hello",a)

     else:
        
        create_greeting_l = lambda a : createGreeting("Greeting",a)

     t = GreeterClass(create_greeting_l,n)
```

Comment: Threads are executed asynchronously. There is no "expected" order of execution here. The only thing that's really guaranteed is that `"Sam"` will be printed first, and that each name will be printed before its associated greeting.

Comment: No Sir please see my full post.
Im expecting: Hello Sam Greeting Sal but Im getting the name Sal on both greetings

Comment: You don’t need threads to get this behaviour. Any code that executes the first function after defining the second has this behaviour; see the duplicate.

Comment: My point stands, even after fixing the closure issue. Once the thread is started, it could be scheduled to execute before the `for` loop continues on to the next name in `nameslist`.

Comment: so how can I fix it where each call preserve the passed parameters

Comment: I dont think the duplicate has anything to do with this post. @MisterMiyagi , executing this code without threads works as expected. Please read the post carefully and dont rush your judgment.

Comment: @samersaleh Of course executing this code without threads works as expected, just as executing the duplicates code without storing the fictions works as expected; the point is that *any* means of delayed execution triggers this. Did you try the *solution* offered on the duplicate, I.e. `create_greeting_l = lambda n=n : createGreeting("Hello",n)`?